# traverse a GUI button grid in c#

Tags: c#, user-interface

Recently I have created a sudoku solver program in c#, and now I am trying to create a visual GUI sudoku game based on my recent code. Now I have placed buttons inside a panel and saw that I can traverse the buttons in the panel like that :

```
 foreach (Button b in this.gamePanel.Controls);
```

however, the traverse seems to be random, Is there any way to traverse these button in 2 for loops as I would traverse a matrix?

Thanks a lot :)
[The buttons grid I created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZP7n.png)

Comment: If your panel is a normal `Panel`, then you can't, the order of the controls is the order with which they were added with. Maybe you can tag the buttons to figure out where they are matrix-wise.

Comment: I usually create a List<List<Button>> game and add the buttons to the list.  The list just links to your existing controls to you can access the buttons either through the list or individually and read/change the same object.

Comment: let's say I do tag them how do I access the button with the ??? tag?

Comment: @jdweng Do you maybe have a code example for how to do it? it's my first GUI project in c# I already did some GUI in JavaFX but it seems to be different here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int WIDTH = 60;
        const int HEIGHT = 60;
        const int SPACE = 3;
        const int ROWS = 9;
        const int COLS = 9;
        List<List<Button>> buttons = new List<List<Button>>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
            {
                List<Button> newRow = new List<Button>();
                buttons.Add(newRow);
                for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
                {
                    Button newButton = new Button();
                    newButton.Width = WIDTH;
                    newButton.Height = HEIGHT;
                    newButton.Top = row * (HEIGHT + SPACE);
                    newButton.Left = col * (WIDTH + SPACE);
                    newButton.BackColor = (row / 3 + col / 3) % 2 == 0 ? Color.Red : Color.Black;
                    newRow.Add(newButton);
                    panel1.Controls.Add(newButton);
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Amazing I will try it now. Thanks

Comment: I added background color to the buttons.

Comment: I actually used a different method to add the colors 
for rows: 
            if(row % 3 == 0 and row != 0 ) change color
            for cols:
                      if(col % 3 == 0 and col ! = 0 ) change color 

but your way looks good as well