# (C#) Load from text file to create a grid of picture boxes

Tags: c#, picturebox, windows-forms-designer, streamreader

I am trying to load from a text file that is formatted as such:

```
a - Total Number of rows in file
b - Total Number of columns in file
x - Row Value for each picture box
y - Column Value for each picture box
z - Picture Value for each picture box
```

a and b are to be used to create a grid of picture boxes.
x and y and z are to be used to place each picture box, and set its picture
The x,y and z portion repeats until grid is full.

File example:

```
2
2
0
0
0
1
0
1
0
1
2
1
1
3
```

This example is for a 2 x 2 grid, so the first picture box would be located at 0,0 and have a picture value of 0. How would you go about taking this information and creating a grid of Picture boxes?

Comment: Are you SCALING those coordinates to bigger values, or using those coords to place the PictureBoxes into maybe a TableLayoutPanel?

Comment: Is all data in ONE LONG ROW of the file?

Comment: I apologize for formatting issues, the data is in a single colum, just one number per line

Comment: Buttons and pictureboxes are both controls.  So organizing into a grid is the same.  See my solution at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61679110/traverse-a-gui-button-grid-in-c-sharp

Comment: You didn't answer the second question. Are you going to scale those coordinates and place your PictureBoxes directly into a container using absolute coords?...or are you going to use a TableLayoutPanel (or something else)?

Comment: Sorry, I will be taking these these coords and using a panel. So for example if the first picture box's top left corner is 10,10 in the panel, and each picture box is 50x50, then the coords for them would be 10,10 - 60,10, - 10,60 - 60,60

Comment: K. So how do the number of rows, cols come into play if you are just calculating absolute coords? Are you calculating the 50x50 size based somehow on the height/width of the panel divided by the number of rows/cols? How do you know to start at (10,10) for the upper left?

Comment: And what do you mean by "Picture Value for each picture box". What are you supposed to do with the number for that value?

Comment: Ok, so the picture box value is just the image that will be used in that picture box. I have an enum that has assigned a number to each image. The file contains information for a game board. So the board is however big, I have included the rows and cols in the file as I figured it would be easier to create the board size and then assign the image to the picture box by coord. The coords refer to the picture box location on the board

Answer (score 0):

Why list the coords in the file? If you list the number or rows and columns as the first two lines, then you can simply list the value for each PB. You just have to decide the order of the values.

For instance, if you listed by rows first:

```
2
2
0
1
2
3
```

This means we have a 2x2 board with the following values:

```
(0, 0) = 0
(1, 0) = 1
(0, 1) = 2
(1, 1) = 3
```

After getting the number of rows/cols, you can use a set of nested for loops to read the value from each line, knowing where each one goes:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rows, cols, z;

    Point pbOrigin = new Point(10, 10);
    Size pbSize = new Size(50, 50);

    String filePath = @"C:\Users\mikes\Documents\Test\data.txt";           
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            rows = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
            cols = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine($"rows: {rows}, cols: {cols}");

            for (int row=0; row<rows; row++)
            {
                for(int col=0; col<cols; col++)
                {
                    z = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
                    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
                    pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle; // just so I can see it
                    pb.Location = new Point(pbOrigin.X + col * pbSize.Width, pbOrigin.Y + row * pbSize.Height);
                    pb.Size = pbSize;
                    // ... do something with "z" ...
                    // pb.Image = z;
                    Console.WriteLine($"({col}, {row}) = {z}");
                    panel1.Controls.Add(pb);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Reading File: " + ex.ToString());
        
    }            
}
```

GUI:

[image]

Console Output:

```
rows: 2, cols: 2
(0, 0) = 0
(1, 0) = 1
(0, 1) = 2
(1, 1) = 3
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Appreciate it!